# unable to restart httpd.service on centos 7 after the configuration of openstack-dashboard

Tags: openstack, centos7, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron, openstack-horizon

Actually I configured controller node having few services like Identity, image, compute and network. After the completion of these , I checked httpd service status and it was active. However I again restart httpd service (systemctl restart httpd.service). At this point it was successfully restarted but when I configured openstack-dashboard then I tried to check httpd status , unfortunately it was in a inactive state. I tried very hard to restart this service through out all possibilities like restart system, enable ,disable or start services, reinstall httpd but I failed. Thanks in advance who will be able to sort out my problem .

Comment: What are you tried?

Comment: I'm trying to configure multi-node openstack installation like compute , network and controller using openstack-newton version.

Comment: Are you checked httpd error logs?

Comment: @e42d3 yes I did. nothing in such file

Comment: @e42d3 yes I did. Nothing in such file